# how to do a conditional assignment to a column in python?

Tags: python

I have a Regex function in Google Data Studio Dashboard that creates a "Channel" column in the dataframe.

```
CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(business_partner, ".*Accounting.*|.*Ecosystem.*|.*Platform.*|.*Agency.*") THEN "Partner"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(utm_source, '.*Facebook.*') THEN "Facebook"
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(utm_source, '.*Google*') AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH(utm_campaign,".*branding.*") THEN "Google"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(utm_campaign,".*branding.*") THEN "Branding"
    ELSE "Others"
END
```

How can I replicate this code in python? something like df['channel'] = ...

| channel |
| --- |
| Facebook |
| Google |
| Partner |

I did a lot of research on the internet, but didn't find anything very conclusive.

Here a sample of data:

| utm_source | utm_campaign | business_partner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| facebook | conversion |  |
| Google | Search |  |
| Google | Branding |  |
| Direct |  | Agency |
| facebook | traffic |  |
| Google | Display |  |

Comment: Halo could you provide an input sample~?

Comment: Of course! I've added an example of the data at the end of the question. Does it help you?

Comment: Sure I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy, straightforward solution using `np.select` ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data_string = io.StringIO("""utm_source utm_campaign    business_partner
facebook    conversion  
Google  Search  
Google  Branding    
Direct      Agency
facebook    traffic 
Google  Display """)
df = pd.read_table(data_string, sep='\t')

conditions = [(df['utm_source'].str.lower() == 'facebook'),
              (df['utm_source'].str.lower() == 'google'),
              (df['utm_source'].str.lower() == 'partner')]
channels = ['Facebook', 'Google', 'Partner']
df['channel'] = np.select(conditions, channels, default=np.nan)
df['channel'] = np.where(df['utm_campaign'] == 'Branding', 'Branding', df['channel'])
```

Comment: Perfect @PPP! In the case where I want to separate the Branding channel from Google, what would it look like? That is, if the utm_campaign contains 'Branding' the channel will no longer be Google but Branding

Comment: @Marjorie Added one more line in my solution, using `np.where` to conduct if-then-else statement